# jq case insensitive contains

Tags: json, jq

Does jq contains support case insensitive matching?

Given this filter:

```
.user | contains("thinking")
```

and the JSON:

```
{
  "id": "1338268256814161923",
  "user": "Thinking of going through the Venmo transactions on my feed and liking all of them just to create a little sense of vulnerability"
}
```

Output is "false", but I'd like to get "true".

jq has an `i` flag for `test` and `match`. Is there anything similar for `contains`?

Comment: See [filter json via bash - case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718102/filter-json-via-bash-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It often suffices to convert both strings to the same typographical case using `ascii_upcase` or `ascii_downcase`, as in your case:

```
.user | ascii_downcase | contains("thinking")
```

If you want to test for equality of strings, ignoring (ASCII) case, you would write something along the lines of:

```
(S|ascii_upcase) == (T|ascii_upcase)
```

If you wanted to test for equality ignoring case more generally, then you should consider anchoring the regex, e.g.

```
.user | test("^thinking$"; "i")
```

Finally, in light of some of the comments, please also note that `S | contains(T)` does a substring match when S and T are both strings.

Comment: My bad! Yes, read the documentation. Thank you.

Comment: hmmm, this doesn't give the requested result for the example provided by the OP. [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/NpMVEtILAF).

Comment: @ikegami - You seem to have overlooked the first sentence of my response, in all its generality.  The additional information was related to one of the OP's comments.

Comment: Re "*You seem to have overlooked the first sentence of my response*", You're right, I didn't mention how atrocious it is. That said, I have no idea why you point out the first sentence. `ascii_upcase` doesn't work for the example the OP provided either. [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/BJ3Qx3qLoK).

Answer (score 5):

If you're ok with providing a regular expression, you can use `test`.

```
.user | test("thinking"; "i")
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/VeSwVQ4i4Y)

---

Comments made by the OP lead me to believe they might want to find *words*. For a simple definition of word, you could use the following:

```
.user | test("\\bthinking\\b"; "i")
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/guD2GFiM8W)

Comment: Problem with this is, this is not exact string matching. eg. Incase test("think"; "i") it would start flagging "thinking" also true.

Comment: Re "*this is not exact string matching*", Correct. `"thinking" | test("think"; "i")` returns `true`, just like `"thinking" | contains("think")`, just as requested.

Comment: @FightDaily - Based on your comment, please note that `contains` is more like `test` than you seem to think.

Comment: Ahh!! Yes, thankyou @ikegami | It seems I was thinking of contains as in of special case, but basically all of the three follow the same thing.